# Between... And... To work without values

Tags: forms, ms-access, wildcard, between

I've tried to do this in a million different ways. At first I couldn't get it to work at all, but now I've managed to get it to work if I put in values. 
What I need to happen is for my query to filter my records based on what I put into my form.

I've used this code in the 'Criteria' section of my MovieYear column, and when I put in numbers into my MovieYear1 and MovieYear2 text boxes in my form, it filters correctly.

```
Between [Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear1] And [Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear2]
```

But if I don't put in any values, it doesn't come up with any records at all. Any help?
I've tried pretty much everything (well, at least I think I have). I've tried using wildcards "*" but then I found out you can't actually use them with Between functions...

I've also trying doing Me.Filter in VBA, but it didn't seem to work. Maybe I just missed something?

This is my [form](http://i.imgur.com/Ci14n0S.png?1).

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Re: "I've also trying doing Me.Filter in VBA" - after you set the `me.Filter` property did you set `me.FilterOn = True`?

Comment: @GordThompson, yes I did. I also did Debug.Print after that too. But it just wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check for a Null in the form to the query, for example

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Between [Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear1] 
      And [Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear2]
      OR [Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear1] Is Null
```

This will return all records if the first year is null. The second year will be ignored.

Comment: Oh my. Thank you so much! You are a savior! :)
I've literally been trying to figure this out for weeks! Once again, thank you!

When I added that to the criteria, it moves the '[Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear1] Is Null' to a new column and the '[Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear1]' is under the 'Field' row, and 'Is Null' is under the 'Or' row. Is that what it's meant to do? So my SQL looks like this: ((MovieList.MovieYear) Between [Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear1] And [Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear2]) AND ..... OR ((([Forms]![SearchForm]![MovieYear1]) Is Null))

Comment: Access has its own ideas about layout that drive some people mad. You are safe enough with most of the changes, although it has a nasty habit of making in-line connection strings fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `conditional` query builder where after checking the value of the boxes you could build the query as per the following cases :

1. if only `MovieYear1` is given then data from all years after `MovieYear1` that is `date>MovieYear1`.
2. if only `MovieYear2` is given then data from all years after `MovieYear2` that is `date<MovieYear2`.
3. if both are given then use the `between clause` to get the data.

This can be implemented using `CASE WHEN` along the lines of following

```
CASE WHEN MovieYear2 IS NULL then date>MovieYear1
else when MovieYear1 IS NULL then date<MovieYear2
else date between MovieYear1  and MovieYear2
```

Comment: CASE is not available in MS Access.